# Change POM configuration programmatically using Java

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a simple Java program that uses a POM file that I would like to edit at runtime. All I need to change is one "version" field to be picked up by my program and added to the POM. I am wondering if it is possible to access a variable named "ver" from my java program and update it in the POM like below, ex:

```
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>group.id</groupId>
                <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
                <version>${ver}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
```

Is this doable? The only variable I want to change is "version". If not, I know there are the MavenApp3 Reader and Writer classes, but they didn't seem to have any method for simply changing a single line (seemed to be more used for writing an entirely new POM, which I am not looking to do). Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The main purpose is to then create a help:effective-pom from the new one, then do parsing on the pom that creates.

Comment: Why would you like to change the version of the pom ? Why not going vice versa?

Comment: I'm creating effective pom's from my base pom.xml file. I want to be able to change the version of the effective pom that I am creating at runtime.

Comment: I hope you don't think that a Java program can access the POM it was build with. Or this what you are trying?

Comment: I don't understand your approach what the problem is you are trying to solve? Can you explain more in detail what you are trying?

Comment: Haha nah sorry - I definitely wasn't wording this properly. I figured it out just by using XPath and rewriting the POM. I'm using a different POM and running Maven commands on it within my Java program. I have it working as intended now (probably should've just asked how to edit an XML file rather than include the POM/Maven info).